# Как минимизировать html на back-end с помощью ejs?

Tags: node.js, шаблоны

Есть node.js приложение в котором в качестве шаблонизатора используется EJS.
Есть ли возможность, не меняя EJS на что-либо другое минимизировать выходной html? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(ejs({intermediate: function(input) {
    return minify(input);
}})
```

https://github.com/mde/ejs/issues/52

Comment: Допустим я сделал так: app.engine("ejs",require("ejs-locals"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(ejs({intermediate: function(input) {
  return minify(input);
}}));   В итоге получаю: ReferenceError: ejs is not defined

Comment: Откуда должна взяться переменная ejs ? не могу разобраться

Comment: var ejs = require('ejs')

Comment: говорит что ejs не функция

Comment: Попробуйте ```express --ejs```

Comment: не хочет, пробовал ejs.render(str, data, {rmWhitespace:true}); тоже толку ноль

Comment: Вроде бы здесь описано как сделать https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2188#issuecomment-56994236 но я не пойму как это заюзать в моем приложении